# Ensure that notification show up on Android even if app is not opened

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, alarmmanager

I am building an app that is needed for a research experiment.
The experiment is entirely based on users responding to notifications that are shown at somehow random intervals.
What is the best way to do this so that each notification will definitely be shown to the user?

WHAT IS DONE SO FAR

I have used AlarmManager and broadcast receiver but notifications stop showing up after some time. Notification Channels (with id) are used too.
I suspect the operating system removes the app after it has stayed in the background for a while.

Can anyone help to explain the best way to get the app to show notifications regardless?

Since this is an app for research, users are well aware of any slow performances, or battery usage. The only priority is to ensure that notifications show up. Without this, the whole experiment will fail.

Any help or pointers will be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what method you've used to show notifications so I'm giving a general guidance.
You will need to use a [background service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service) which keeps running even after the app has closed. A background service can be killed by the android OS if its running low on memory, so you'll have to give permission to your app to autostart.
If you want even more reliability, you should use a [Foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services). This way you can give high priority to your notification service.

But it would be much simpler to integrate [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) into your app than implementing your own NotificationBuilder service.

Comment: The app only needs user interaction when a notifications is clicked. To my understanding, the foreground service is not intended for this use case. Correct me if I am wrong. Also that app is suppose to work even in offline mode, does firebase cloud message allow for this?

Comment: Its true, a foreground service is not used for NotificationBuilder in general, but its the only way to ensure 100% that your notifications are received on time. Any other method will, to some extent, be subject to your android device's mercy. In my experience though, FCM is still quite reliable for your needs.

Comment: I have implemented a WorkManager  and currently testing the results. Thanks for the pointers @Mythos